# Calculating only the current and previous rows in a Pandas data series

Tags: python, pandas

New to python. I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this but I'm struggling to find it.

I have a series of positive and negative numbers. I want to know what percentage of the numbers that are positive. I've accomplished that for the whole dataset but I would like the calculation to occur on every row.

The dataset I'm working with is quite large but here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'numbers': [100, 300, 150, -150, -75, -100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['count'] = df['numbers'].count()
df['pct_positive'] = df.numbers[df.numbers > 0].count() / df['count']

print(df)
```

Here is the actual result:

```
   numbers  count  pct_positive
0      100      6           0.5
1      300      6           0.5
2      150      6           0.5
3     -150      6           0.5
4      -75      6           0.5
5     -100      6           0.5
```

Here is my desired result:

```
   numbers  count  pct_positive
0      100      1           1.0
1      300      2           1.0
2      150      3           1.0
3     -150      4           0.75
4      -75      5           0.66
5     -100      6           0.5
```

note how 'count' and 'pct_positive' are calculated on each row in the desired result and are simply totals in the actual result.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the calculation of `pct_positive` for both positive and negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `'Count'` is redundant with your index, so you can create that column based on the index (or just stick with the index). `.cumsum` a boolean `Series` checking `> 0` to get the percent positive after dividing by `'Count'`.

```
df['Count'] = df.index+1
df['pct_pos'] = df.numbers.gt(0).cumsum()/df.Count

   numbers  Count  pct_pos
0      100      1     1.00
1      300      2     1.00
2      150      3     1.00
3     -150      4     0.75
4      -75      5     0.60
5     -100      6     0.50
```

Also, avoid naming a column `'count'` as it is a method.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much! And, thank you for the warning on the count column. Your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df.numbers.gt(0).cumsum().div(df.numbers.notnull().cumsum())
```

Output:

```
0    1.00
1    1.00
2    1.00
3    0.75
4    0.60
5    0.50
Name: numbers, dtype: float64
```

Details:

- Get sign of df.number check to see if greater than 0 for positive
  then cumsum that column.
- Count the numbers using notnull to change to boolean and cumsum.
- Divide postive by total count.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the addition, Scott.